# NodeJS: How to have the same code for local / prod environments

Tags: node.js, design-patterns

I'm trying to figure out how to build my app so it doesn't have to differentiate between the environment.

For example I have a function called `UpdateConfig()` which when run on `local` simply reads a json from a path. The same function ran on `prod` reads the same json but gets it from an AWS S3.

A way to code this would be:

```
if( enviroment == LOCAL ) json.readFile('path', ...);
else S3.getObject(options, ...);
```

What approach should I take in order to have the same code for both enviroments?

Are there any general rules I should look out for in order to make sure my code doesn't need to take in consideration what enviroment I'm in?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying whatever an app is in dev or production mode is generally done via the `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable in node.

You can set that variable via commandline (linux): `export NODE_ENV=dev`

or via the `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "set NODE_ENV=dev && node app.js"
 }
```

You can even set it in the app itself, but that's not recommended: `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'dev';`

You can simply check the `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable in your app if it's dev or production. For example:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev') {
    // dev code
} else {
    // prod code
}
```

Warning: the `package.json` method may add an space after dev.

Comment: Thanks for the info! That surely solved my where to store the environments type. Yet, are there any ways to fix my other problem ? Not having different code for different environments. They only thing I can think of is building myself a factory but not sure that's the best way.

Comment: Well I think that if you want to handle things differently, whether you are in dev or prod, you will need different code.